Is there a way to prevent the storybook jsx exporter from condensing specific child tags
I am currently creating a jsx component in storybook with the jsx plugin however, I want to maintain the child specific child tags in the jsx export. Currently, if I am returning a new component, all the child tags are condenses. The alternative I am attempting is exporting a template however, there are specific functions/react states that are not being exported properly.
I have tried to componentize the template however, this just condenses all the child tags. I have also tried creating a wrapper component however, I am not getting the desired jsx output

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
